# How to check is ajax enabled in woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a shop based on Wordpress WooCommerce.

I can check / uncheck that option in the options of WooCommerce.

Is it possible to detect with php if ajax is enabled??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this option??

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

If yes,

```
$ajax_cart_en = 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_ajax_add_to_cart' );
if ($ajax_cart_en) { echo 'ajax is enabled'; }
```